# Deploying react on ubuntu droplet

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I've got a locally perfectly working react app on port 3000.

Finally bought a droplet, installed and configured **nginx + ssl**.
Everything 'normal' is working just fine.

When i'm deploying my react app, npm server starts, looks normal but...
mydomain.net, mydomain.net:3000 etc. is just not working (i see only my html file, no react rendering).

What i'm missing?

Comment: It's not possible to know from just what you've told us. Check the browser devtools for any errors or resources that failed to load. Maybe you have hardcoded `localhost` somewhere? Typically you would use port 443 for ssl / https. To use it on port 3000 might require some changes in your configuration. A typical setup is to use nginx to serve the app on port 443, not port 3000. Do you use an app server such as express to render the react application, or is it just client side?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to configure NGINX as a reverse proxy?
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

eg adding in NGINX configuration file:

```
location / { 
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; 
proxy_http_version 1.1; 
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade'; 
proxy_set_header Host $host; 
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
}
```